# Вызвать static конструктор без обращений к классу

Tags: c#, static

Возможно ли, какими нибудь окольными путями (меняя код в рамках одного класса Test), заставить программу на старте вызывать статик конструктор класса Test?

Как я понимаю, шарп, в каком то смысле, оптимизирует программу, и не выполняет построение статик конструкторов до тех пор, пока имя класса не встретится в коде? Есть ли способы заставить шарп построить класс, который нигде не упоминается, но, включён в сборку?

```
using System;

namespace Program {

    public static class Test {
        static Test() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");   
        }
    }

    public class Activator {

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("start...");
        }

    }

}
```

Поясню, я хочу увидеть в консоли:

> Hello World!
>
> start...

Comment: "меняя код в рамках одного класса Test" - нет. Как нам не хватает Delphi-евского блока `initialization` :)!

Comment: @Igor, это печальные новости :(

Comment: Автор, а что ты пытаешься сделать? Это какая-то инъекция кода, которую ты хочешь выполнить в момент загрузки сборки?

Comment: @LunarWhisper, найти все классы которые программист пометил как сервлеты, создать их экземпляры, и закинуть в класс-библиотеку. Таким образом, аналогично яве, программисту можно было бы просто создать класс, пометить его как сервлет, и сервер уже сможет перенаправить соответствующие запросы (в соответствии с критерием запроса) на этот сервлет и заставить его сформировать ответ. В общем, по сути, спрятать весь этот механизм от программиста-пользователя.

Comment: @LunarWhisper, А так да, по сути, это инъекция.

Comment: @test123 Дело в том, что для выполнения статичного конструктора тебе нужен какой-то поток. Потоки сами по себе не стартятся, ты должен это сделать явно (или делегировать задачу потоку из пула). Если ты это делаешь явно, значит у тебя уже есть какой-то доступный для программиста код в сервере. Ну, а если он есть, то там же ты можешь пробежать по типам, как это сделано в примере ниже. Но это выглядит не лучшей системой плагинов...

Comment: @LunarWhisper, >> Но это выглядит не лучшей системой плагинов<< с точки зрения запуска - да, и довольно медленно оно стартует, но, дальше, после создания словаря, запрос является ключём, по нему можно сразу получить класс-хандлер для формирования ответа. Мне важно удобство в том, что я смогу добавлять и убирать запросы, и добавлять и убирать классы-хандлеры для ответов, при этом, всё это вообще можно вынести в отдельный проект.

Comment: Но для этого вовсе не обязательно использовать инициализацию через статичные конструкторы. Ты точно так же можешь найти типы, создать их экземпляры, проинциализировать, зарегистрировать их в словаре и использовать в дальнейшем. Держать же логику инициализации в статичном конструкторе, ошибка в котором закрашит всё приложение... не уверен, что это хорошая мысль. Но тебе виднее. ;)

Comment: @LunarWhisper, а, ну да, я ввёл в заблуждение, ваш код я адаптировал в класс Loader, он просто собирает все классы с атрибутами и создаёт их экземпляры в словарь. Никаких статик конструкторов тут уже нет. Идея со статиками провалилась) 
https://pastebin.com/Mv8c8zP0 - вот он.

Comment: Ну и отлично, очередной велосипед удалось свести к классическому решению. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Без дополнительного вызова (хотя бы одного), который запустит инициализацию твоих типов - нет, нельзя. С ним можно.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Program
{

    [InvokeStaticCtorAttribute]
    public static class Test
    {
        static Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    public class Activator
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InvokeStaticCtorAttribute.InitializeStaticCtors();
            Console.WriteLine("start...");
        }

    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class InvokeStaticCtorAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public static void InitializeStaticCtors()
        {
            foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (type.GetCustomAttribute<InvokeStaticCtorAttribute>() != null)
                        RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66687/discussion-on-answer-by-lunar-whisper--static----).

Comment: Воспользуюсь вашим вариантом, во всяком случае, если понадобитсья добавить ещё подобных модулей, такого вопроса больше не возникнет.

Answer (score 2):

Для комментария слишком много, для ответа... в общем пусть пока повисит, там видно будет.

Для приведенного примера статического конструктора мало что можно сделать, так или иначе класс упомянуть в коде придется.

Если же нужен доступ к статическим константам, как, например, в классе `Math`, или значениям из файлов конфигурации, то можно довольно легко выйти из положения, вспомнив о том, что свойства, на самом деле, являются одним или парой методов. Таким образом, для констант или значений из конфигурации, которые нужно получить без явного вызова методов инициализации, достаточно заменить поля на свойства (readonly для констант). Обращение к статическому свойству равноценно вызову статического метода, а значит с тем же успехом заставит CLR загрузить класс и вызвать статический конструктор.

Comment: Спасибо за идею) Добавлю плюсы в оба ответа, хотя, первоначальную задачу они не решают.